# How do I iterate over the vectors of all but one axis of a numpy array (tensor)?

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

Suppose `p` has shape (4, 3, 2).  I want to iterate 12 times over arrays of size (2,)

```
    q = np.empty_like(p)
    op_axes = [list(range(len(p.shape) - 1)) + [-1]] * 2
    it = np.nditer([p, q],
                   op_axes=op_axes,
                   op_flags=[['readonly'], ['writeonly', 'allocate']])
    with it:
        for this_p, this_q in it:
            print(this_p.shape)   # I want this to have shape (2,)
            this_q[...] = some_function_of(this_p)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for v in p.reshape(-1,2).T`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I still need to produce `q`, which `nditer` does.

Comment: You can always reshape the list back to q.shape. But you better vectorize `some_function`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't vectorize `some_function` or else I wouldn't be doing any of this iteration in the first place.  `some_function` is essentially a root-finder.

Comment: ‘np.array((some_function(v) for ....)).reshape(q.shape)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang  That works.  It would be nice do it with `nditer` for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can do:

```
    q = np.empty_like(p)
    for i in np.ndindex(p.shape[: -1]):
        this_p = p[i]
        ...
        q[i] = solution.x
```